# Get reference to ViewHolder at position in RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with displays a List of items. One Item of this list should be my currentItem `(int)`, that Item should be expanded. For that, I have this method `expand()` in my `ViewHolder`. I  want to call this method when `currentItem == position` is.

I thought I could do it like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final WorkoutExcersiseHolder excersiseHolder = (WorkoutExcersiseHolder) holder;
    excersiseHolder.expand(currentExcersisePointer, position);
    if (currentItem == position) {
        excersiseHolder.expand();
    }
}
```

However every Item gets expanded. So is it possible to get a reference to the ViewHolder at only one position in my `RecyclerView.Adapter`?

Comment: In this case, the `position` is the position of the current `ViewHolder` hence `currentItem == position` will always be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind your current item number to the model which you use to fill your `RecyclerView`. In your case I guess it is `WorkoutExcersiseHolder` class, which should have something like `isCurrent()` method, which will help to `onBindViewHolder` decide to expand it or not. Update your model list with your logic and then use [`RecyclerView.Adapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) method `notifyItemChanged`.  For your note, also don't use `position` parameter to reference current `ViewHolder`, but instead try to use `holder.getAdapterPosition()`

Comment: Ok thank you! If I do it this way, how can I tell the next item in my List, to set isCurrent, when I click on a Button? Because I want to be able to switch throuh my items with a "next" Button.

Comment: you can set property in your model `boolean isCurrent=false`, and then on your button click you can make it true, but making all other `false` beforehand, and then notify your adapter about the changes (this is rough approach you can start with it), (more efficiently you can keep reference to your currentItem model and disable only on it), if this helps don't forget to mark answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should hide the item when the condition is false.

```
if (currentItem == position) {
    excersiseHolder.expand();
} else {
    excersiseHolder.collapse();
}
```

When you change the currentItem's value you should call notifyItemChanged() with the old value and the new one too.

```
notifyItemChanged(currentItem);
currentItem = newPosition;
notifyItemChanged(currentItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

pass view holder object to the expand method and then expand throw this object in the expand method